# Como sincronizar hilos en C con OpenMP

Tags: c, hilos, multitasking

Tengo este código que trata de hacer una Serie Geométrica usando OpenMP , pero al final no se obtiene el mismo resultado que cuando se ejecuta de manera secuencial.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIM 1000000000

int main(void)
{
    float serie;
    long int i;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        #pragma omp for 
        for(i = 1;i <= LIM;i++)
        serie += (1 / (float)i);
        #pragma omp barrier
    }
    printf("La Serie es: %.5f\n",serie);
    return 0;
}
```

El resultado correcto: 15.40368

Cuando se trabaja con OpenMP da valores esporádicos en cada ejecución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define LIM 1000000000

double calculate(long value)
{
  double toReturn = 0.;

  for( ; value ; value-- )
    toReturn += 1.0 / (double)value;

  return toReturn;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%.5f\n",calculate(LIM));
}
```

La ejecución de este programa arroja un resultado de

```
21.30048
```

Que difiere mucho del resultado que indicas, `15.40368`. ¿El motivo? `float` dispone de únicamente 6 dígitos representativos, el resto pueden considerarse basura. Uno puede pensar que 6 dígitos dan mucha precisión... pero en tu caso, es decir, en 1e9 iteraciones el error es significativo. Dicho de otra forma, cuando `i>1e7` ya estás acumulando un error aproximado de 10 y en `i>1e7` de 100.

Mientras trabajes con `float` para esta operativa no vas a obtener un resultado correcto jamás.

Por otro lado tu código tiene una condición de carrera:

```
    #pragma omp for 
    for(i = 1;i <= LIM;i++)
      serie += (1 / (float)i); // <<--- AQUI!!!
```

Si explotamos un poco el código obtenemos algo similar a esto:

```
    #pragma omp for 
    for(i = 1;i <= LIM;i++)
    {
      double temp = serie;   // (1)
      temp = temp + 1.0 / i;
      serie = temp;          // (2)
    }
```

Tu estás asumiendo que `openmp` va a deducir que `serie` es una variable común a todas las iteraciones y que debe cuidar que no se produzcan lecturas sucias que alteren el resultado final y no es así. Lo que sucede es que uno de los dos hilos puede acabar sobreescribiendo el valor del hilo anterior: los dos hilos pasan a la vez por (1) y después pasan por (2), lo que sucede es que únicamente prevalece el segundo valor.

Para evitar esa inconsistencia tienes que modificar la definición del bucle:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:serie)
    for(i = 1;i <= LIM;i++)
      serie += (1.0 / i);
}
```

Lo que hace el modificador `reduction` es que asigna a cada hilo de ejecución una copia de `serie`, de tal forma que cada hilo modificará su propia versión de la variable. Cuando ambos hilos finalizan se suman las dos versiones de la variable y el resultado se almacena en la variable `serie` que tu has definido.

```
#pragma omp for reduction(+:serie)
//                        ^  ^^^
//                        |  variable a dividir
//                        operacion a ejecutar para fusionar los valores
```

Como nota final, `#pragma omp barrier` no es necesario en este caso ya que la propia definición del bucle paralelo incluye la correspondiente sincronización de los hilos.

Resumiendo, tu código debería lucir así:

```
#define LIM 1000000000

int main()
{
  double serie = 0; // No olvides inicializar las variables
  long i;
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
  {
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:serie)
    for(i = 1;i <= LIM;i++)
      serie += (1.0 / i);
  }
  printf("La Serie es: %.5f\n",serie);
  return 0;
}
```

**NOTA**: Si aun te queda alguna duda sobre el resultado final puedes comprobar el valor correcto en este [enlace](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2Fi,%20i%3D1%20to%201e9)

Comment: Se ve interesante , pero a pesar de todo veo que casi no hay cambios y la reducción de la autosumarización ya se había experimentado y no hay cambios previos.

Comment: @JuanCarlosLanuzaL No te entiendo

Comment: Me refiero a que la variable por su alcance causaba el problema como un overflow de información dentro de un float. Por ser un numero tan grande ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosLanuzaL tenías dos problemas: condición de carrera al leer y escribir en `serie` y problemas de precisión por el uso de `float`

Comment: Correcto, ya entendí. Trabajo con Micro-arquitecturas y pues a veces no se pueden usar variables muy grandes por el simple hecho que las SRAM no son tan vastas como tener 4GB o 8GB de DDRAM. Pero estamos claro, vamos a tener que pedirle mas SRAM a los Micro Controladores.